# What is a mult-dimensional dictionary?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I've found functions that define multi-dimensional dictionaries, but I'm unclear what they look like.

Comment: It's just a dictionary that stores dictionarys, really.  Same as a multidimensional array...

Comment: Sounds like it's dictionaries within dictionaries (nested).  Whereas you access a value in a dictionary as `d[key]` in a multidimensional dictionary it would be `d[key1][key2]`.

Comment: How do you know that those functions define multi-dimensional dictionaries, if you don't know what they are or what they look like?

Comment: Just because they say they do in other stackoverflow posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values in a dictionary can be any Python object, including another dictionary.  For example:

```
animals = {'pets': {'George': 'cat', 'Fred': 'dog'}}
```

You can access one the values of the inner dictionary using a key lookup on `animals` like `animals['pets']['George']` or `animals['pets']['Fred']`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems more proper to call it a `nested dictionary` since the term `multidimensional` fits better to a regular shape, or rectangular shape, like (3x4x5x6).

A nested dictionary is a dictionary that contains another dictionary in one of its values, similarly to a nested list which is a list that contains another list in one of its values

Nested dictionary:

```
nested_dict = dict( a=1, b=2, c=dict(c1=2, c2=2), d=3, e=dict(e1=dict(e11=1, e12=2), e2=1))

{'a': 1,
 'b': 2,
 'c': {'c1': 2, 'c2': 2},
 'd': 3,
 'e': {'e1': {'e11': 1, 'e12': 2}, 'e2': 1}}
```

Analogy with a nested list:

```
nested_list = [1, 2, [2,2], 3, [[1,2],1]]

[1, 2, [2, 2], 3, [[1, 2], 1]]
```

Comment: I think that this was part of my confusion!